# Android Map within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps

I want to enclose the **map within a Fragment**. I tried with 2 approaches.

1. **Enclosing map within fragment using Tabhost**. But this uses *LocalActivityManager* which is a deprecated method. I wanted to use without this method, but unable to proceed.

It is throwing IllegalException when I try to call mTabHost.setup(); for setting up my tabs.

1. **Directly using Fragment and FragmentActivity** : Referred [here](https://gist.github.com/977234) . But unable to use methods to fetch the Current User Location.

Kindly let me know how to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `MapActivity` can load a `Fragment` that contains a `MapView`, on API Level 11 and higher -- see [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkFragments) for an example of how this is done.

However, this does not work with the fragment backport in the Android Support package. There is no good way to handle that, unfortunately, at this time.

Comment: Isn't there a way to have the tabs with - TabHost and TabWidget without using LocalActivityManager?

Answer (score 5):

Google released the [Map API Version 2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). This gives you a MapFragment and a [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment). This allows you to add a Map without extending MapActivity.